# PayPal Checkout v2 SDK .NET problem with PayPalHttp.HttpResponse

Tags: javascript, vb.net, paypal-sandbox, fetch-api, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm having a problem in the last part of a transaction setup flow:
the client side correctly calls my backend which makes a call to PayPal to create the order and receives a response with status code 200.

The error occurs when the http response is returned to the client, here we realize that the json that was created by the paypal class is incomplete! There are no closing parentheses that invalidate the json.  "} ] }"

I asked the paypal team for assistance but it is not helping me. They continue to go around the problem, saying that the bees always return the complete json to me, but I know this too, because in debug mode the result gives me a link that correctly sends me back to the paypal payment.

This makes me understand that in reality the flow that I created is complete but the PayPalHttp.HttpResponse class creates an incorrect body.

I am attaching the code.

```
Public Shared Async Function CreateOrder(ByVal Optional debug As Boolean = False) As Task(Of PayPalHttp.HttpResponse)

    Dim result As New Order
    Dim request = New OrdersCreateRequest()

    request.Prefer("return=representation")
    Dim newRequest As New OrderActionRequest
    request.RequestBody(BuildRequestBody(dicNameValue))


    Dim response = Await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request)

    If debug Then
    result = response.Result(Of Order)()
    Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", result.Status)
    Console.WriteLine("Order Id: {0}", result.Id)
    Console.WriteLine("Links:")

    For Each link As LinkDescription In result.Links
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "{0}: {1}" & vbTab & "Call Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method)
    Next

     /*--- HERE THE PROBLEM ----*/
    Dim json As String = PayPalClient.ObjectToJSONString(result)
    Console.WriteLine("Response JSON: {0}", json)
    /*----------*/

    Dim amount As AmountWithBreakdown = result.PurchaseUnits(0).AmountWithBreakdown
    Console.WriteLine("Total Amount: {0} {1}", amount.CurrencyCode, amount.Value)

    End If

    Return response
  End Function
```

*This is the incomplete json :*

```
{
  "create_time": "2020-03-18T14:28:56Z",
  "id": "2LW612087K897524T",
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v2\/checkout\/orders\/2LW612087K897524T",
      "method": "GET",
      "rel": "self"
    },
    {
      "href": "https:\/\/www.sandbox.paypal.com\/checkoutnow?token=2LW612087K897524T",
      "method": "GET",
      "rel": "approve"
    },
    {
      "href": "https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v2\/checkout\/orders\/2LW612087K897524T",
      "method": "PATCH",
      "rel": "update"
    },
    {
      "href": "https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v2\/checkout\/orders\/2LW612087K897524T\/capture",
      "method": "POST",
      "rel": "capture"
    }
  ],
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "breakdown": {
          "handling": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "10.00"
          },
          "item_total": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "180.00"
          },
          "shipping": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "30.00"
          },
          "shipping_discount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "10.00"
          },
          "tax_total": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "20.00"
          }
        },
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "230.00"
      },
      "custom_id": "CUST-HighFashions",
      "description": "Sporting Goods",
      "items": [
        {
          "category": "PHYSICAL_GOODS",
          "description": "Green XL",
          "name": "T-shirt",
          "quantity": "1",
          "sku": "sku01",
          "tax": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "10.00"
          },
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "90.00"
          }
        },
        {
          "category": "PHYSICAL_GOODS",
          "description": "Running, Size 10.5",
          "name": "Shoes",
          "quantity": "2",
          "sku": "sku02",
          "tax": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "5.00"
          },
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "45.00"
          }
        }
      ],
      "payee": {
        "email_address": "sb-bzfcs1123474@business.example.com",
        "merchant_id": "55J4WA53G7WRL"
      },
      "reference_id": "PUHF",
      "shipping": {
        "address": {
          "address_line_1": "123 Townsend St",
          "address_line_2": "Floor 6",
          "admin_area_1": "CA",
          "admin_area_2": "San Francisco",
          "country_code": "US",
          "postal_code": "94107"
        },
        "name": {
          "full_name": "John Doe"
        }
      },
```

PS: the project is in VB.NET 4.6.1 (web forms)

Answer (score 0):

> Dim response = Await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request)

What is `response` here?

And can you debug the value further in, within `PayPalClient.client().Execute(request)`

PayPal sends JSON over the network. So it seems you are receiving JSON, which is converted into an Object, and then you are calling a function on that object that gives back JSON.

I am not sure *why* that particular function is giving bad JSON at the moment you call it, but I do know that the original JSON from PayPal is probably complete.

Comment: response is a `PayPalHttp.HttpResponse`, these are all the classes provided by the paypal dll.

Comment: the PayPalClient.ObjectToJSONString (result) method is used only to check what those classes are doing. Paypal doesn't seem to want to give me credit that there is something wrong with their .NET classes.

Comment: There may be something wrong with their .NET classes, but the data received as JSON should be okay, and the data inside the classes is probably okay as well. It's when you convert the class from being an object *back* to JSON that you're throwing a few too many wrenches into the process

Comment: So my suggestion is, backtrack a little. Examine the contents of the class as a datastructure (without converting it to JSON), and better yet examine the JSON received over the network from PayPal in the HTTP request.  It should all be valid and complete.

Comment: The technical support department showed me that the json they send is complete, then said to look for answers here on stackoverflow because they can't help me, finally they linked me this: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK/tree/develop/PayPalCheckoutSdk/Orders. 
You were more understanding you in a few lines rather than Paypal in 5-6 emails.

Comment: as you want to see from the link anyway, the conversion to json is not done by me, but is done directly by their classes (metadata) in the body of the `response (paypal.httpresponse)`

Comment: Got it, yes I could see you are calling a function on their object to convert back to JSON, but why? This isn't something you normally need to do. It's normal to (1) use the JSON as received, and (2) perform operations on an object.  It's not very normal to convert that object back to JSON. There may be a bug here, but I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish / why you are triggering this ".ObjectToJSONString" method except for debugging purposes (which I am saying it is not good for)

Comment: So if you think there is something wrong with `result`, debug this `result` object as a VB .net object